# APC UPS model:BR550ci-in How to Disable Minimum Load Turn Off

Tags: ups

I got an APC UPS (Model No:BR550ci-in). I need to light a bulb(40w, 230volt) from it.  The problem I am facing is **Minimum Load Turn Off**. My UPS auto-detects the load and if it doesn't meet the minimum requirement, the UPS turns off, which is good feature to get maximum from your UPS. But sometimes I only need to light the bulb (don't need the computer to work). Due to **Minimum Load Turn Off**, this can not be achieved.

So my question is **how can I disable this feature (Minimum Load Turn Off) ?**

Can I remove some part of the circuit to disable this feature? If so, which elements?

Or is there is another workaround for my problem?

Comment: I looked at the specs and the user manual and couldn't find any mention of minimum load turn off.  Where did you find this information?  The specs show a performance curve equivalent to 75 watts, so worst case, you could try a bigger bulb, like 60W, and see if it is enough.  You probably don't want to start modifying the circuit.  Have you tried contacting APC tech support?

Comment: The model you're talking about is a Back-UPS ES.  This is an entry-level UPS with very little that can be configured.  However, I've connected these to devices that draw less power than light bulb and didn't have the problems you describe.